Error submitting job: '400 Client Error: Not defined HTTP error, Error code: 2413.'
When I am trying to run the below code, I am getting the error Error submitting job: '400 Client Error: Not defined HTTP error, Error code: 2413.'. Is there something wrong with qiskit?
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit import transpile

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(0,2)

qc.measure_all()
print(qc.draw())
IBMQ.save_account('PUT YOUR KEY', overwrite=True)
IBMQ.load_account()
IBMQ.providers()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
print(provider.backends())
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_kyoto')

 transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc_combine, backend=backend)
max_shots = 100000
job = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots= max_shots)
print(job.job_id())













[<IBMQBackend('ibm_sherbrooke') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_brisbane') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_kyoto') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>, <IBMQBackend('ibm_osaka') from IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/session.py", line 278, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1024, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api-qcon.quantum.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqbackend.py", line 389, in _submit_job
    submit_info = self._api_client.job_submit(
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/clients/account.py", line 227, in job_submit
    job_info = self.account_api.create_remote_job(
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/rest/account.py", line 209, in create_remote_job
    return self.session.post(url, json=payload).json()
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/session.py", line 300, in request
    raise RequestsApiError(message, status_code) from ex
qiskit.providers.ibmq.api.exceptions.RequestsApiError: '400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api-qcon.quantum.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs. Not defined HTTP error, Error code: 2413.'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m99693/RESEARCH_WORK_Latest/ORNL_2023_CODES/TESTING_HW_RUN_AFTER_MITIGATION/sending_to_hw.py", line 51, in <module>
    m3_mitigator.cals_from_system(final_maps)
  File "/home/m992c693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mthree/mitigation.py", line 209, in cals_from_system
    self._grab_additional_cals(
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mthree/mitigation.py", line 431, in _grab_additional_cals
    _job = self.system.run(circs, shots=shots, rep_delay=self.rep_delay)
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/utils/deprecation.py", line 251, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqbackend.py", line 338, in run
    return self._submit_job(qobj, job_name, job_tags, experiment_id, live_data_enabled)
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqbackend.py", line 399, in _submit_job
    raise IBMQBackendApiError('Error submitting job: {}'.format(str(ex))) from ex
qiskit.providers.ibmq.exceptions.IBMQBackendApiError: "Error submitting job: '400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api-qcon.quantum.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs. Not defined HTTP error, Error code: 2413.'"

Edit1
Somehow things have changed in IBM-qiskit. When I tested the code Hello world program in Qiskit 1.0 with two hardware ibm_sherbrooke and ibm_kyoto and it do generate the request.

But the API in qiskit==1.0 are very different, especially how to how to save, load, and putting that hub, group, and project thing. It would be great if I can be helped on this?

I assume you actually put your API key in the save_account function? And can you share your Qiskit version please?

Thank you @TristanNemoz for the response. Yes, I added the key. Today, it suddenly stopped working.  My qiskit version is qiskit==0.43

The latest qiskit version is 1.1.1, maybe the API works only for qiskit >= 1.0. Can you update qiskit and tell us whether you still have the problem?

Thank you @TristanNemoz. I think recently qiskit no longer supports previous versions. I have edited the question. It would be great if I can be helped on that.

I'm not sure what your problem is now? What are you trying to accomplish, which qiskit version are you using, and what is the error that you get? Btw, if I'm not mistaken, only a single one of hub, group and project is required (but I don't remember which one)

Is your question "How to submit jobs using qiskit 0.46 even though it's not supported anymore"?

Thank you @TristanNemoz. I have to now migrate my project code to qiskit==1.0. Somehow, now I not able to submit job using qiskit==0.43 which was working till last week. Thank you for great help.

It's likely that the API changed at the same time Qiskit was upgraded to 1.0. Updating your code shouldn't be too much of a hassle, but if you don't manage to do it, don't hesitate to post a new question to solve that problem. You can also look at the migration guide to Qiskit 1.0 which should be useful! That said, if your problem was that you had to update your qiskit version, is it OK for you if I close this question?

Yes, you can close the queston @TristanNemoz.  Thank you.
